# Looping through empty javascript array returns array object functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, associative

I noticed that in my javascript, if I create an empty array, loop through it as an associative array, and print out the contents, it returns what looks like functions from the Array Object class itself. Here is my code:

```
var test = new Array();
for(var i in test){
    document.write(i + " " + test[i] + "<br>");
}
alert(test.length); // this returns 0
```

The above code prints the following (I'm omitting some of the output since it's kind of long)

```
$family function (){return u; }
$constructor function Array() { [native code] }
pop function pop() { [native code] }
push function push() { [native code] }
reverse function reverse() { [native code] }
shift function shift() { [native code] }
sort function sort() { [native code] }
splice function splice() { [native code] }
unshift function unshift() { [native code] }
concat function concat() { [native code] }
join function join() { [native code] }
slice function slice() { [native code] }
indexOf function indexOf() { [native code] }
etc...
```

I noticed that if I loop through the array using a for loop ie:

```
for(var i = 0; i < test.length; i++)
```

the browser doesn't print out anything (which is what should happen)

Can anyone explain why I'm getting a bunch of functions from an empty array when I loop through it the other way? In case it matters, I'm using mootools v1.3. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `var test = [];` would be nicer instead of using `new Array()`

Comment: Just in case, what browser does this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get rid of whatever extends `Array.prototype`. Extending the prototype of default types like `Array` or `Object` is bad and causes problems like that.

The easy way to circumvent issues while keeping the prototype extensions is adding a `if(!test.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;` check. (`obj.hasOwnProperty(key)` is `true` if the property is on the object itself and not only somewhere in its prototype chain)

Besides that, you shouldn't use `for..in` loops when iterating over arrays - use `for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)` in this case.

Comment: This works great in cases where the array is associative and you can't for-loop through the keys. Thanks, I learned something new today!

Comment: "associative arrays" are objects in JavaScript - that's why extending `Object.prototype` is also bad. And yes, in this case using `for..in` is perfectly fine and it actually works without problems and additional code when not extending the prototype.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but I found this while trying to find a way to do this.
This is what I came up with.

```
function createArrayOfEmptyObjects(size) {
    return Array.apply(0, new Array(size).map(function(){return {};});
}
```

It will, as its name implies, create an array of empty objects up to a provided size.